# Buffer and Batch Jobs with Sidekiq

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, sidekiq

I have a sidekiq job that runs very frequently and each job updates a single MySQL database record using ActiveRecord in Rails:

```
HTTP request
  -> RecordUpdateWorker(id, value)
  -> Record.find(id).update(value: value)
```

It's causing <s>deadlocks</s> lock timeouts in the database. There seem to be no duplicate jobs, but the IDs are near to each other, so I can only guess that this is due to [Gap Locks](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/innodb-locking.html#innodb-gap-locks). Regardless, my idea for a solution is to "buffer" the jobs and perform them less frequently in batches. There is no need for them to be executed immediately, so for this use-case it wouldn't cause a problem.

```
HTTP Request
  -> Add Record to Buffer
  -> Occasionally run RecordUpdateWorker()
  -> Record.where(id: ids_from_buffer).update_all(value: values_from_buffer)
  # I'd have lots of flexibility to tune the transaction size, etc here
```

Is there any way to accomplish this with sidekiq or with a sidekiq add-on? I'm already using batches (Sidekiq Pro) in other places, but it doesn't seem like it would fit this use-case. One obvious solution would be to just use a custom Redis queue and a reoccurring job (or something like a `until_and_while_executing` lock in sidekiq-unique-jobs), but if there is a standard way to accomplish this, I'd rather use that.

I've already looked at the sidekiq docs, including pro and enterprise, and didn't find anything that quite matched this description.

Edit: Changed deadlocks to lock timeouts since I'm not sure it's a deadlock scenario.

Comment: Won't sidekiq just retry and eventually everything will finish?

Comment: @Daiku yes in some cases, retries solve the issue, but after 3 retries (the maximum for this job), I often get failed jobs. That's possibly because retries are still subject to thundering herd behavior. It's also a problem because the deadlocks cause a lot of strain on the database, so I'd rather avoid the situation entirely.

Comment: For `.find(id)` you don't have `id` indexed? If so this shouldn't result in a gap lock from my understanding but rather a row lock. Do you have any other competing queries going on in the system that could be resulting in locks around this record?

Comment: @Matthew Yes, I think I don't really understand gap locking very well, and according to the docs, it shouldn't come into play here on my indexed primary key. There is a foreign key referencing another table, and it seems that can cause gap locks, but that's unfortunately where my knowledge ends. If you see that I've made an obvious mistake, I'd appreciate you pointing it out, but otherwise, the direction of my question is more about buffering and batching sidekiq jobs. Thanks though, you've pointed out that I probably need to understand MySQL locking better.

Comment: For the record in question what association does it have and do you have indexes for the primary and parent id? Also I think it’s less about MySQL knowledge  I just wonder if the is other queries causing the row you want to update (which you have indexed) to be locked.

Comment: @Matthew The model, called "Record" above has a foreign key to "ParentRecord" like this: `CONSTRAINT fk_rails_xxxxxxx FOREIGN KEY (parent_record_id) REFERENCES parent_records (id) ON DELETE CASCADE`